# Python Parallel Assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to figure out how this parallel assignment works. The full code can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erdman/alt-python3-halite-starter/150142612fda57219a64e4632208ddaac16ce60f/ProductionBot.py). (Raw Github python file). Here is what I'm having issues with:

```
def assign_move(square):

    # Parallel Assignment
    target, direction = max(
        ((neighbor, direction) for direction, neighbor in enumerate(game_map.neighbors(square))
                                if neighbor.owner != myID),
                                default = (None, None),
                                key = lambda t: t[0].production)
```

I'll break it down as much as I know, but I'm probably doing something wrong.

```
target, direction = max(iterable, default, key)
```

Are we assigning target, and direction to the same thing? I thought parallel assignment was something like `x, y = 5, 6`

Now if we look at the `iterable`, it is the following:

```
iterable = ((neighbor, direction) for direction, neighbor in enumerate(game_map.neighbors(square)) if neighbor.owner != myID)
```

How can we have `(neighbor , direction)` before the for loop? What does the `if` statement here do? Do we not need anything below the if block to run if `neighbor.owner != myID`?

If the iterator is empty, we will return `None, None` as seen below?

```
default = (None, None),
```

And this is the function we are using to determine the max?

```
key = lambda t: t[0].production)
```

Background if needed:
This is code for a bot to be played in the game [Halite](https://halite.io/). It is a prebuilt bot found in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/erdman/alt-python3-halite-starter).

Comment: That's not a `for` loop with an `if` statement; it's a [list comprehension with a filter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Ahh perfect! I had no idea what to even search for for that part.

Comment: @Hamms: Genex, not LC. No square brackets.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams would it be [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) then?

Comment: @Loaf: Correct.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams does it matter if we used square brackets in this case?

Comment: The square brackets result in a list, which may take up a lot of space depending on how large the source is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max` function here return the maximum `tuple` of `(direction , neighbors)` with respect to `neighbor.production` ( as we understand this from `key`) and neighbors are allowed to participate in this iterate if `neighbor.owner != myID` happens , and if iterator was empty `default = (None, None)` will be `target` and `directions` values , so `target` is the `neighbor` with most `production` at the end.

Comment: if it was `t[1].production` it would be `direction.production`?

Comment: Yeah , assume `t` here is your `tuple` so first element is `neighbor` and second is `direction` , and it wont return an error if `direction` class had a `production` member.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation. That makes a lot more sense along with realize that `for` and `if` isnt' a for loop or an if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever there are multiple variables on the left of an assignment, the right side is required to be a sequence with exactly that many elements, which are unpacked into the individual variables.

Sometimes, the right side explicitly builds that sequence: for example, `x, y = 5, 6` is technically the construction of the tuple `(5, 6)`, followed by its unpacking.  (Actually, since Python 2.6 the tuple construction gets eliminated here, but that's an internal optimization that should never be relevant to you.)

However, ANY source of a sequence of the correct length is valid on the right side.  In your `target, direction = max(...)` example, `max` is choosing an element from a list of 2-element tuples `(neighbor, direction)`.  The "largest" one of these (as defined by the **key=** parameter) is returned and unpacked into target and direction.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't initially think about `max(...)` returning anything but a single value.